# Django 2.0 Retrieve data from model with field array

Tags: django, database, python-3.x, django-models, model

I have a model having name, branch, section.

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    branch= models.CharField(max_length=20)
    section  = models.CharField(max_length=5)
```

I can retrieve data from the model using 2 option, tuple and list.

```
model.objects.values_list('name', 'branch')
model.objects.values('name', 'branch')
```

But If I have an array of fields it doesn't work.

```
a = ['name', 'branch']
model.objects.values_list(a)
model.objects.values(a)
```

I need some way if I have an array of fields then I need to retrieve the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These methods expect a series of arguments, not a single iterable. You can use the `*` syntax to expand your list:

```
model.objects.values_list(*a)
```